# Homographic image transformation issue for sattelite images

Tags: matlab, transformation, homography, projective-geometry

I want to apply homography to the satellite images. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346525/homographic-image-transformation-distortion-issue) quite helpful. So I decided to use the same Matlab code.

```
 im = imread('cameraman.tif');
 n = [0;0;-1];
 d = Inf

       theta = 60*pi/180;

       R = [ 1     0           0 ;
           0  cos(theta) -sin(theta);
           0  sin(theta)  cos(theta)];

       t = [0;0;0];

      K=[300 0    0;
            0    300 0;
            0    0    1];

      H=K*R/K-1/d*K*t*n'*K;

     img=imagehomog(im,H','c');
     figure;imshow(img)
```

but the output is just the small box.
I am using MATLAB 2015b
[image]

**EDIT**
Homography using `imtransform` and `maketform`

```
n = [0;0;-1];
d = Inf;

im = imread('cameraman.tif');

   theta = 60*pi/180;

   R = [ 1     0           0 ;
       0  cos(theta) -sin(theta);
       0  sin(theta)  cos(theta)];

   t = [0;0;0];

  K=[300 0    0;
        0    300 0;
        0    0    1];

  H=K*R/K-1/d*K*t*n'*K;

  tform = maketform('projective',H');
  imT = imtransform(im,tform);

  imshow(imT)
```

Output
[image]

How can I do it from the center. Something like this
[image]

Comment: That code does not run, its full of bugs. `imagehomog` is not a MATLAB fucntion

Comment: Yes its not a matlab function. I used the code as it is mentioned in the post. If it is full bugs then how he showed an output in the answer?

Comment: I have no idea, because your `for` loop has no `end`, so MATLAB can not run that code. Can you please link the documentation of `imagehomog`?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected that code, that `for` shouldn't be there.
here is the [code](https://github.com/covarep/covarep/blob/master/external/voicebox/imagehomog.m) of `imagehomg`. Full [description](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/imagehomog.html)

Comment: Oh, so **its not** a function inside MATLAB. I suggest you have a look at [imtransform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html) and the multiple possibilities that [maketform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/maketform.html) gives you. I can not comment in code you found randomly on the internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135906/discussion-between-addee-and-ander-biguri).